# Problemas con PyQt5 connect Signal y slot

Tags: python, pyqt5

No me deja hacer la prueba de conexión, me dice:

> module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'connect'

Yo usaba Qt con C++ pero quiero hacer una funcionalidad en python y quiero hacerlo con señales y slots pero no puedo hacer que conecten. 
Puen darme bien la estructura de declara las señales y los slot y la conexión en la sintaxis de python.

Gracias de antemano

```
from PyQt5 import  QtCore

class Dialog():
    def __init__(self):
   # Define a new signal called 'trigger' that has no arguments.
        self.trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

       # self.trigger.connect(self.handle_trigger)
        QtCore.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('trigger'),self.handle_trigger)

        # Emit the signal.
    def sigEmit(self):
        self.emit(self.trigger)

    def handle_trigger(self):
        # Show that the slot has been called.
        print ("trigger signal received")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Inciando")
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.sigEmit()
    print("acabe")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de usar slots , yo todavia soy novato en esto pero de la siguiente manera me funciona tu codigo:

Simplemente a la clase le he asignado un QObjet que segun he leido [aqui](https://blog.abstractfactory.io/dynamic-signals-in-pyqt/) los pyqtsignal solo funcionan con objetos de QT como QtWidgets QDialog etc

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject,pyqtSignal

class Dialog(QObject):
    trigger = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.trigger.connect(self.handle_trigger)


    def sigEmit(self):
        self.trigger.emit()

    def handle_trigger(self):

        print ("trigger signal received")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Inciando")
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.sigEmit()
    print("acabe")
```